# Why is my crested gecko is trying to burrow and eat soil?

Tags: behavior, death, geckos

A few months back my gecko lost his tail, as of recently his behavior has changed. He used to climb high up and stay there, now he is now on the ground and digging himself in the soil. He has even started to eat mouthfuls of dirt.

I spray him regularly and feed him often, what could be wrong?

Comment: Does he eat normally?